# How do I fix "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error in Vue project?

Tags: javascript, mysql, django, vue.js, axios

I'm making a Vue project and, when making an `axios.post` call in my vue file, I get `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` as an error on the site and a `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js?2d83:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:84)` error right after.

The login method I'm attempting to use that's giving the errors:

```html
login() {
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/', {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
      })
          .then(resp => {

            this.token = resp.data.token;
            console.log(this.token)
            localStorage.setItem('user-token', resp.data.token)
          })
    }
```

The full error:

```html
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js?b50d:177
xhrAdapter  @   xhr.js?b50d:13
dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js?5270:52
Promise.then (async)        
request @   Axios.js?0a06:61
Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js?0a06:87
wrap    @   bind.js?1d2b:9
login   @   Header.vue?0418:44
$data.token.Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed>  @   Header.vue?0418:17
callWithErrorHandling   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling  @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163
invoker @   runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:333
```

settings.py:

```html
"""
Django settings for DB_django_Project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
# This is a test comment. Please remove this.
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'somethinsecret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'DB_Vue_Project.apps.DbVueProjectConfig',
    'myapi.apps.MyapiConfig',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',

]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://localhost:8080',
    'https://127.0.1:8080',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        # basic and session are what we are currently using
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # token authentication failed I believe
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ]
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
#     'contenttype',
# ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DB_django_Project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DB_django_Project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mystdb',
        'HOST': 'fancy.stuff.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    },
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode ='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
    },
}
# settings.py file
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've looked around in Django documentation and around stackoverflow for a couple hours and haven't found any solutions. Any assistance, critiques, comments, or questions would be appreciated. I'd be more than happy to provide any additional information needed.

Comment: Is your server running? Have you configured your CORS settings in settings.py?

Comment: Have you tried sending the POST via a test app like Postman?

Comment: @lockednlevered, I have confirmed that the server is running. The only CORS settings I have in my settings.py folder are `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://localhost:8080',
    'https://127.0.1:8080',
)` and `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`.

Comment: @Stochastis can you post your settings.py?

Comment: @lockednlevered, posted.